# Tensorflow: list of tuples as placeholder

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use `compute_gradients` and generate local gradients. These gradients are to be averaged with multiple local gradients from other machines after which `apply_gradients` will be called. I am using **2** `session.runs` with a `feed_dict` in the second one that accepts gradients. Since `apply_gradients` expects a list of tuples, I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

This is how I am generating the list of tuples placeholder :

```
grads  = cifar10.train_part1(loss, global_step)

xx = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grads[0][0].shape) for i in range(10)]
yy = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grads[0][0].shape) for i in range(10)]


xyz = zip(xx,yy)

train_op = cifar10.train_part2(loss,global_step, xyz)
```

I get the following error :

```
NotImplementedError: ('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_10:0' shape=(5, 5, 3, 64) dtype=float32)
```